# Segfault when compiling with g++ with optimizations

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-optimization

I have a really weird crash in my code (with g++ version 7.3):

When compiling with -o0, everything works fine. But when compiling with -O1/O2/O3, I get a segfault. Running in GDB, it looks like right after returning from a function, there is for some reason a call to _unwind_resume, which segfaults. I didn't see any call to _unwind_resume at the same place in my code with the code compiled with -O0.

But there is more:

- I tried running it with valgrind to see if I get any useful information. It reports "unrecognized instruction at address", but no memory issues.
- I tried using different optimization flags individually, to see if there is a specific optimization that causes this. I used all the optimizations listed by g++ -Q -O1 -help=optimizers. No crash. I tried to use all the relevant -f flags together. Still no crash.
- I tried compiling with clang++ instead of g++, with any optimization level. Again, works ok with no crash.

I guess the call stack somehow gets corrupted with the optimized code in g++, but I have no idea why or what to do about this. Any idea how to approach it?

Note: unfortunately, I'm unable to share the code, and it's too big for sharing it here anyway.

Edit: I managed to reduce the code that causes the error. Here is a reproducer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Expr;

typedef std::vector<Expr*> ExprVec;


enum class Ops {
    Search
};

enum class ExprKind {
    Const,
    Function,
    Unknown
};

namespace Values {
class Value
{
public:
        virtual ~Value() {};
};

class String : public Value
{
public:
   String(const string& v): _val(v) {}
   String(const char* s): _val(s) {}

   ~String() {
   }

   static const string name;

private:
    string _val;
};

const string String::name = "String";

} // Values

class Expr
{
public:
   Expr() {}
   Expr(const ExprVec& args)
     : _args(args) {}

   virtual ~Expr() {
    for (auto arg: _args) {
        delete arg;
    }
   };

   virtual Values::Value* run() = 0;

protected:
   ExprVec _args;
};

template<class ValType>
class ConstExpr: public Expr
{
public:
    ConstExpr() {}
    ConstExpr(ValType* val)
       : _val(val) {}

    ~ConstExpr() {
        delete _val;
    }
    virtual Values::Value* run() {
        return _val;
    }


private:
   ValType* _val;
};

typedef ConstExpr<Values::String> StringExpr;

// This is a template for all expression nodes. Instantiate for each expression
template <ExprKind Kind, Ops Name, class RetVal, class Arg1>
class ExprT: public Expr
{
public:

    ExprT() {}

    ExprT(const ExprVec& args)
      : Expr(args) {}

    virtual Values::Value* run() {
        Arg1* arg1= dynamic_cast<Arg1*>(_args[0]->run());
        return run(arg1);
    }

    RetVal* run(Arg1* arg1);
};

typedef ExprT<ExprKind::Function, Ops::Search, Values::String, Values::String> Search;

template<>
Values::String* Search::run(Values::String* arg1)
{
}

int main()
{
    Values::String* str = new Values::String("blahbla");
    Expr* se = new StringExpr(str);
    ExprVec args({se});
    Expr* search = new Search(args);
    search->run();
    cout<<"Done\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Edit2: I just realized this is not an actual reproducer. Search::run returns no value here, and in the original code, it does return a value. I'll try to create a better reproducer.

Update:
I finally figured it out ... the example above wouldn't be able to reproduce the specific bug, because it requires at least two source files and one header file. The problem was, I had some function with non-specialized template definitions in the header file, and fully specialized template instantiations of those functions in one of the source files.

I did not declare the specializations in the include file, which was the source of the problem ... I only figured it out when I tried to compile it on Windows (instead of Linux), and got linking errors due to multiple instantiations of the same functions.

Comment: I suggest trying to reduce it to an [mcve]. Doing so, you will probably ferret out at least one instance of [tag:undefined-behavior].

Comment: I finally figured it out ... the example above wouldn't be able to reproduce the specific bug, because it requires at least two source files and one header file. I'll add an update and it could be flagged as resolved.